# PHP Grab first word from line

Tags: php, string

I have a file that looks like this (with newlines and weird spacing):

```
Player:         Alive: Score: Ping: Member of Team: 
player1         No     16     69    dogs      
bug             Yes    2      63    insects            
name with space No     0      69    cats        
bob             No     0      69    dogs
```

How can I grab the first column and turn it into an array?

**Desired Output**:
 $players[1] ----> "player1" 
 $players[2] ----> "bug"
 $players[3] ----> "name with space"
 $players[4] ----> "bob"

Comment: are they columns tab delimited or all spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with Iterators:

```
class SubstringIterator extends IteratorIterator
{
    protected $startAtOffset, $endAtOffset;

    public function __construct($iterator, $startAtOffset, $endAtOffset = null) {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->startAtOffset = $startAtOffset;
        $this->endAtOffset = $endAtOffset;
    }

    public function current() {
        return substr(parent::current(), $this->startAtOffset, $this->endAtOffset);
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
$playerIterator = new LimitIterator(
    new SubstringIterator(
        new SplFileObject('yourFile.txt'), 
        0, // start at beginning of line 
        15 // end before Alive:
    ) 
    , 1 // start at line 2 in file (omits the headline)
);
```

You can then `foreach` over the iterator, e.g.

```
foreach ($playerIterator as $player) {
    echo $player, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
player1        
bug            
name with space
bob
```

Or transform the stacked Iterators into an array:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($playerIterator);
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => player1        
    [2] => bug            
    [3] => name with space
    [4] => bob            
)
```

[Demo of above examples with your file's data](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mJ6o83)

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    $a=file('file.txt');
    $pos=strpos($a[0],'Alive:');
    $res=array_map(function($x) use ($pos){
        return trim(substr($x,0,$pos));
    },$a);
    unset($res[0]);
```

For PHP 5.2-

```
<?php
    $a=file('file.txt');
    $pos=strpos($a[0],'Alive:');
    function funcname($x,$pos){
        return trim(substr($x,0,$pos));
    }
    $res=array_map('funcname',$a,array_fill(0,count($a),$pos));
    unset($res[0]);
```

Comment: using `unset` leaves the array starting with index 1. `array_shift()` is better. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: try to check "Desired Output:" again ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: It seems to me that this is intended behavior as the OPs array started at 1 too.

Comment: @Nobody: Excuse me, what does OP mean?

Comment: @RiaD it means ["Original Poster"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op&defid=419306).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in script.php on line 99. Hm, could you explain :)

Answer (score 3):

Another option using a regex could look like:

```
preg_match_all('/^.{0,15}?(?= {2}|(?<=^.{15}))/m', $subject, $matches);
$players = $matches[0];
unset($players[0]); // remove header

var_export($players);
```

The resulting `$players` array looks like

```
array (
  1 => 'player1',
  2 => 'bug',
  3 => 'name with space',
  4 => 'bob',
)
```

**Note:** As with any regex-based solution, if the above looks like magic then *please don't use it*. There is absolutely no point copying and pasting a regular expression into your code if you've no clue what it is actually trying to match.

Comment: What will happen if maximum the maximum length of player's name will exceed 15 chars? :)

Comment: The answer above only deals with the example file given in the question. If the OP wants it to handle other input, detail that in the question so that answerers know the limits and bounds to work with.  P.S. It's a trivial fix to change the length checks.

Comment: Than it's the same answer as mine, but mine has -1 votes ;) BTW for what purpose do you use assertions? In fact, the only thing script needs to do is to get first N chars from every line :) Then the regexp should be just `/^(.{15}).*$/m` where 15 is max column width :]

Comment: The assertions are there so that the matches don't have the trailing whitespace.

Comment: i think the warning on "don't use it if you don't understand it" is a bit harsh - theres a bit of learning curve on regex, and actually using a few helps you learn

Comment: @ErichBSchulz by all means, *use it*.  As the answer says, I'm against blind copy/pasting; not against using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
$file = file_get_contents($filepath);
$column_width = strpos($file,'Alive:') + 1;
preg_match_all('/^(.{'.$column_width.'}).*$/m', $file, $matches);
unset($matches[1][0]);
$result = array_map('trim', $matches[1]);
```

The final $result is:

```
array (
    0 => 'player1',
    1 => 'bug',
    2 => 'name with space',
    3 => 'bob',
  ),
```

Comment: this regex applied to the first data-row-string leads to an array containing just "n". looks nifty though

Comment: this is not the OPs intended outcome. Look again at the post.

Comment: Are you talking about "Desired Output"? The question is "How can I grab the first column and turn it into an array?" So what's wrong? With this code you'll get an array. The only problem I see is with names with spaces.

Comment: I think, the only problem for OP is name with space too

Comment: @RiaD: OK, fixed it again. Not so nifty though ;D

Comment: for some reason, i get this warning `Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in script.php on line 98`

Comment: @Kevin Duke: provide the path to file, not file content.